# pass event object and other parameters to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know similar questions have been asked, but I couldn't find any answer.
There is a JavaScript function:

```
function init(url) {
    $('#id_search').keyup(function() {
        performsearch(url, e);
    });
}
```

I am trying to pass event object and the url parameter to the `performsearch` function:

```
function performsearch(url, e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('perf->' + url);
    }
```

But `e.preventDefault()` gives an error:

> e is not defined

What is wrong in this function call?

Comment: well e is never defined....

Comment: `.keyup(function(e){` rather `.on("input", function(e){` ?! The `oninput` event will trigger also on copy paste etc events...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the `event` from the `keyup`'s callback function.

```
function init(url) {
    // Get the event parameter of the callback function
    $('#id_search').keyup(function (e) {
        performsearch(url, e);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with closure. Your problem may be solved using other solutions but you might encounter problems later on that you might need this technique.

```
     $('#id_search').keyup(function(url) {
         return function (evt) {
             evt.preventDefault();
             console.log('perf->' + url); 
        };

     })();
```